# How to adjust the properties of the 'large' image size in ACF plugin for wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

For the ACF (advanced custom fields) plugin for wordpress, in its wysiwyg editor field, I want to be able to change the default image size of the large image property to make it responsive instead of having it set to a defined height and width in pixels. Is there a way to adjust this? Either with css or by adjusting the core files of ACF? Basically I would want the html code wrapping my image to be something along the lines of

```
<img src"url/path/to/image" width="100%" height="auto">
```

instead of

```
<img src"url/path/to/image" width="1024px" height="576px">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS I use to make WordPress WYSIWYG images responsive:

```
.entry-content img, .comment-content img, .widget img, .entry-summary img, .wp-caption { max-width: 100%; }
img[class*="align"], img[class*="wp-image-"], .comment-content img[height], .entry-content img, .entry-summary img, img[class*="attachment-"] { height: auto; }
img.size-full, img.size-large, .wp-post-image, .post-thumbnail img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```